# Non-static method

Tags: java, non-static

I have a class here that is meant to move a gun in a window when a key is pressed. However, I am getting an error about referencing the non-static method from the type. Here are the two parts. The error comes at the two "if (k == ....." lines.

```
private class Keyboard extends KeyAdapter {

    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {

        int k = e.getKeyCode();

        if (k == 39) {Gun.move(10);}
        if (k == 37) {Gun.move(-10);}

    }

}
```

---

```
public class Gun {

        private Color color;
        private int A,B,C,D;
        private int E,F,G,H;

        public Gun (Color c) {

            color = c;
            A = 375;
            B = 550;
            C = 50;
            D = 10;
            E = 395;
            F = 540;
            G = 10;
            H = 10;

        }

        public void move(int xAmount){

            A = A + xAmount;
            E = E + xAmount;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Error message says it all: you're trying to access an instance method of `Gun` without a `Gun` instance.

Comment: If you have to ask, I doubt us telling you will help. You need to read more java tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

Which `Gun` ? You need an *instance* i.e. a reference to a `Gun` object created thus:

```
Gun gun = new Gun(...);
gun.move(amount);
```

Your `Keyboard` object will have to somehow have a reference to this `Gun` object, or perhaps to some manager-type object that knows that you're trying to move a `Gun`.

Answer (score 0):

Your **move method** is a **non-static method**, thus it should be invoked with an instance of a class Gun.

```
    Gun gun = new Gun();//creating an instance of a Gun class.            
    if (k == 39) {gun.move(10);}
    if (k == 37) {gun.move(-10);}
```

Comment: I actually have already done this earlier in the class that holds Keyboard.

Comment: 'private Gun G;

public Shooter (Color x) {
  
  setBackground(x);
  
  G = new Gun (Color.blue);
  
}'

Comment: To call a method of a specific instance of the class, you will need to use that instance. So if you saved your `Gun` into the variable `G`, you will need to call `G.move(10)`

Comment: Then you have to work with field `G`. Naming conventions indicate that you should use lowercase `g` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A static method is one that is not specific to a given instance of the object. It does not operate on anything that makes one gun different from another (the instance variables). Your move method is not static. It moves a certain gun.

When you call it as:

```
Gun.move(10)
```

You are calling it on all guns, not on a certain gun (hence the error about a static method). In order to move a gun, you have to have a gun that you want to move. Hence, you need to create a new gun (using `new Gun(...)`).

Comment: "You are calling it on all guns" => wrong. He's calling it on a method (static) independent of any Gun's instances. Static method belongs to class, not primarily associated to "the whole of all instances". Since each instance is associated to its class, therefore we each static method is accessible by each object.